Equivalence of two definitions of differentiability on non-open sets
I am looking for a reference, or simple argument, that would shed light on the following two definitions of the derivative of a multivariate function.
Let $E\subseteq\mathbb R^n$, not necessarily open, and let
$$f\colon E\to\mathbb{R}.$$
Suppose $x_0\in E$ is not an isolated point.
First definition: $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ if there exists a linear map $A\colon\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ such that the error
$$\|f(x)-f(x_0)-A(x-x_0)\|=o(\|x-x_0\|).$$
The derivative $f'(x_0)$ is then equal to $A$, provided that it is unique.
Second definition: $f$ is differentiable at $x_0\in E$ if there exists an open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ containing $x_0$, and a function $F\colon U\to\mathbb R$ which is differentiable at $x_0$ such that $F|_{U\cap E}=f|_{U\cap E}$. In that case $f'(x_0)$ is defined to be $F'(x_0)$.
Question 1: Are these two definitions equivalent?
Question 2: If so, is the supposition that $f'(x_0)$ be unique necessary in the first definition?
Comment: My suspicion is that the two are equivalent even when $f'(x_0)$ is not unique according to the first definition; in that case different extensions should be possible. Similarly, if $x_0$ is isolated then one can extend the function in many ways. So it would make sense that the second definition subsumes the first. However, I'm not able to find a clean reference that discusses these questions.

This is only a partial answer.
Your second definition has to be modified as follows:

$f$ is differentiable at $x_0\in E$ if there exists an open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ containing $x_0$, and a function $F\colon U\to\mathbb R$ which is differentiable at $x_0$ such that $F|_{U\cap E}=f|_{U\cap E}$.

The part "In that case $f′(x_0)$ is defined to be $F′(x_0)$" does not make sense unless all $F$ with the above property have the same derivative at $x_0$. This uniqueness requirement is similar as that in Definition 1.
It is obvious that if $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ in the sense of Definition 2, then so it is in the sense of Definition 1.
Let us add
Third definition: $f$ is differentiable at $x_0\in E$ if there exists an open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ containing $x_0$, and a function $F\colon U\to\mathbb R$ which is differentiable at $x_0$ such that $\lVert f(x) - F(x) \rvert = o(\lVert x - x_0 \rVert)$ for $x \in U \cap E$. Note that this requires $F(x_0) = f(x_0)$.
Again $f'(x_0)$ is only defined if all such $F$ have the same derivative at $x_0$.
Clearly $(2)$ implies $(3)$.
$(3)$ implies $(1)$:
We know that $\lVert F(x) - F(x_0) - F'(x_0)(x - x_0) \rVert = o(\lVert x - x_0 \rVert)$, thus
$$\lVert f(x) - f(x_0) - F'(x_0)(x - x_0) \rVert = \lVert f(x) - F(x) + F(x) - F(x_0) - F'(x_0)(x - x_0) \rVert \\ \le \lVert f(x) - F(x) \rVert + \lVert F(x) - F(x_0) - F'(x_0)(x - x_0) \rVert = o(\lVert x - x_0 \rVert).$$
$(1)$ implies $(3)$:
Take $F(x) = A(x)$.
Whether $(3)$ implies $(2)$ is not known to me.

Thank you, I have edited the question according to your suggestion. Also it seems that in the case when E is closed one might be able to use Whitney's extension theorem as done here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51249/extension-of-a-function-to-a-differentiable-function
